# How to filter object from array by value and using the value to omit another array or objects?

Tags: arrays, underscore.js

I have a array, which has the bunch of object, i would like to filter the object by 'name' value, again i would like to omit those object from another array of object  using underscore.

I know that we can do using earch, but i am not getting the proper approach to do this both..

any one help me to do this?

example :

incoming array:

```
var incomingArray = [
    {"name":"apple"},
    {"name":"orange"},
    {"name":"dog"},
    {"name":"cat"},
    {"name":"egle"}
];
```

filter keys:

```
var omit = ['orange' ,'dog'];
```

//i need to check whether 'orange' or 'dog' are exist, if so..

```
var filtered = _.filter(incomingArray, function(obj, i){
    return obj.name === omit[i]['name'];//this is wrong i need to loop again how?
});

var anotherArray = [
        {"name":"apple"},
        {"name":"orange"},
        {"name":"dog"},
        {"name":"cat"},
        {"name":"egle"}
]
```

return only the array without the omit like this:

```
  var outgoingArray = [ 
    {"name":"apple"},
    {"name":"cat"},
    {"name":"egle"} ]
```

how we could achieve this with proper approach?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kcnk3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there! Use indexOf to check that the name does not belong in the omit array:

```
var filtered = _.filter(incomingArray, function(obj) {
    return omit.indexOf(obj.name) == -1;
});
```